# Laravel 5 - Add exceptions rendering logic from a package

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

I'm developing a package for Laravel 5 and I'd like to add the rendering logic of my own exceptions to the default `ExceptionHandler`.

I don't want to replace the default Laravel 5 exception handler, just want to let the application where my package is installed be aware of how my package exceptions should be rendered.

How can I do that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to replace the application exception handler, you could do so in your service provider. While it might be nice to extend from the application exception handler it would be difficult because it might not be named `App\Excpetions\Handler` if the developers have changed the application namespace.

```
$app->singleton(
    'Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler',
    'Vendor\Package\ExceptionHandler'
);
```

Otherwise, you might consider providing a trait that a developer can pull into their own `ExceptionHandler` and leverage your additional functionality that way.

Comment: Thanks @dwight for your reply :) So you suggest to create a trait with a method that renders my exceptions and ask the user to call that method within `render()` of his exception handler, right?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my suggestion. A trait seems like the easiest way to hook into Laravel's exception handler without removing any of the developer's control.

Comment: Ok got it, I hoped there was a way to register my exceptions rendering logic in the service provider. Thanks man :)